# How to manually install and set up server jre in /usr/lib/jvm?

Tags: linux, installation, debian, java

I would like to install a second jvm on a debian system. However, I can't just do `sudo apt-get install opend-jdk-xyz` because I don't want to overwrite any global jvm settings. Instead I would like to run this jvm next to the standard one. I'm also using the Oracle Server-JRE.

How would I install the JRE? I have it unpacked in my home directory but I'm completely unaware how and what rights I should set or if I need to add the JRE to a user group or anything like that. The Oracle manual for manual installation just says "unpack the tar into the directory of your choice and it's installed" is that enough?

Answer (score 0):

I just copied the JRE to /usr/lib/jvm and it worked. :)